# prior for integer-valued random variable taking values 1 or greater

Tags: distributions, bayesian, model, prior

In my model I have an integer-valued random variable which should only take values one or greater. I would like to specify an appropriate prior for this which has most of the mass say around 1 to 5 and decays close to 0 beyond that. I was wondering if someone knows of a distribution that satisfies these conditions and I can use it model this RV.

Comment: I corrected from "discrete" to "integer-valued" if this is not what you mean please specify "discrete" properly.

Comment: All distriubutions over $\mathbb{N}^*$ can be used as priors. A standard one would be a drifted Poisson $\mathcal{P}(1.5)+1$, i.e., a Poisson rv drifted by $1$. I picked $1.5$ to get a mean of $2.5$.

Comment: Excellent example of how "incorporating prior beliefs" is a non-trivial job. And kudos for trying

Comment: Thank you for the comments and encouragement. I would upvote but do not have enough privileges. So, with the Poisson example, the mean can be real but I am guessing I am interested in the mode which can be integer valued.